# VSIX extension install but item-template not shown in visual studio

Tags: c#, vsix, itemtemplate, sidewaffle, vsixmanifest

Currently I am Learning VSIX Item Template And Make simple item-template by referring this link

https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/07/a-step-by-step-guide-to-developing-visual-studio-item-templates-using-sidewaffle/

[this is my project picture that show I made sample item template project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaiAY.jpg)

I follow all step that mention in above link and after that I build project and then I found vsix extension in debug folder than I install it.

after install it i start another instance of vs2013 and check that extension is install or not and i found that extension is installed correctly.

then I do right click in view folder => go to add => new item  then in new dialog box I search SampleTemplate but it not found.

I don't know why i dont found this in my viusal studio.

I found this item-template in computer in blow path but not in vs2013.

C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp\Extensions\MyNiral\VSIXProject1\1.0\Output\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\My Custom Templates

please help me thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I basically had the same problem. Try to delete the Installation Targets in your `.vsicmanifest`. In my case, I noticed that I couldn't edit them any more and I didn't have to, but I deleted and recreated them the same way they were and somehow that fixed the problem.

Another approach I read about, is that the path name for the templates destination becomes too long to process for the installer, so maybe if you shorten the project and -map Names and try again.

If that doesn't help, try to make a new VSIX-project and add your .zip documents there.